# Store answer with javascript to temp array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 10 questions with "YES" and "No" answers. I need user to answer all of them. If all answers marked as "Yes", "Next" button should be enabled. If at least one answer "No" disabled.

Could you please show me how it can be done with javascript or jquery library?

Here is an example of my HTML, lets assume I have 2 questions

```
<p>
Question?<br />

<input type="radio" name="Question1" value="Yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="Question1" value="No" />No
</p>
<p>
Question 2?<br />
<input type="radio" name="Question2" value="Yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="Question2" value="No" />No
<p>
<button id="next" type="button">Next</button>
```

Comment: I'm thinking to add answers to array and then compare it. but the problem is I don't have so much experience on client side

Comment: too much left unsaid... your yes and no, are they drop down menus, are they radio buttons?  What is the id/name/value/class of the items?  It would be very helpful if you provided the actual html you are working with.

Comment: I updated my question with HTML example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(e){
    var $yes = $('input[type="radio"][value="Yes"]');
    if ($yes.filter(':checked').length === $yes.length) {
        $('#next').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#next').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

[See example →](http://jsfiddle.net/5umgp/)